# how to make a folder of images accessible in node.js mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i wrote an api node.js mysql and i created a folder called images in the same directory with index.js file , but when go to http://localhost:3000/images/bike.png a message says that Cannot GET /images/bike.png

the same message also for Cannot GET /images

my index.js file

```
/*  RESTFUL SERVICES BY NODEJS */

var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


//connect to mysql
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost' ,
    user:  'root' ,
    password: '',
    database: 'nodeapp'
})


var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('images/'));

//connect to database
con.connect((err) =>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Mysql Connected...');
  });

/Server listening
app.listen(3000,() =>{
    console.log('Server started on port 3000...');
  });
```

how to make images folder accessible and to go to the bike.png by url

Comment: Try `app.use(express.static('images'));` without the slash.

Comment: i did it but http://localhost:3000 also says can not get , http://localhost:3000/images the same thing , is there a query or something that i must write??? i feel something is missing here   , and for idea my post queries worked all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should remove the trailing slash in `app.use(express.static('images/'));` as @ptothep already mentioned.

If you don't indicate a route for static assets they will be accessible from a root URL like this `localhost:3000/bike.png`.
If you wish to map `images` folder to `/images` then indicate this route like this:

```js
app.use('/images', express.static('images'));
```

See [Static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)